# How do we use a boolean on a where statement in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, boolean

I have another problem with PLSQL and would like to ask for your help. To explain the problem I will use a simple example: I have a table "tab" having for columns "code" and "description" and a function returning a boolean. I would like to select every code, description such that myFunction(code)=true.
I tried this statement:

```
SELECT code, description from tab where myFunction(code)=true
```

I got this error :

> ORA-00900 : invalide SQL-statement.

Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `BOOLEAN` is a [PL/SQL data type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS003) and does not exist in [SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021).

If you want to return a truthy value then return a literal (i.e. `0`/`1` or `'Y'`/`'N'` etc.) and compare that.

```sql
SELECT code,
       description
FROM   tab
WHERE  myFunction(code) = 1
```